# How to copy row from one data.frame in to another [R]

Tags: r, copy, dataframe

There are two data frames x, y .
Id like to copy row with number J from X into Y.
Something like

```
    Y[1,] <- X[j,]
```

Comment: Do x and y have the same structure (number of columns, data types)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely the same type.

Comment: Justin, the question is how to do it in R. I'm a newbie in R (also in programing), so sorry for a such dumb question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example happens to pretty much answer your question. (Try it out!)

If, instead of *replacing* a row in the target data.frame, you want to *add* a row to it, try `rbind()` instead:

```
X <- data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:3], value=1:3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Y <- data.frame(name=letters[1:3], value=rnorm(3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

X[1,] <- Y[1,]
X <- rbind(X, Y[3,])
```