# Partial merge in R

Tags: r

Before I end up at -7 like [Two by two matching between dataframes in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123013/two-by-two-matching-between-dataframes-in-r) did, let me say I've already read the following pages:

- [How to copy row from one data.frame in to another [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013985/how-to-copy-row-from-one-data-frame-in-to-another-r)
- [R How to update a column in data.frame using values from another data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427043/r-how-to-update-a-column-in-data-frame-using-values-from-another-data-frame)
- [Using one data.frame to update another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971513/using-one-data-frame-to-update-another?rq=1)

Actually, the last one is really similar to what I want, but not the same, because my columns are different

I have two dataframes, let's say:

```
> d <- data.frame(year=c(2004,2004,2006),month = c(1,5,3), height = c(1000,2000,3000) )
> d
  year month height
1 2004     1   1000
2 2004     5   2000
3 2006     3   3000

> e <- data.frame(year=c(2004),month=c(5), height = c(9999))
> e
  year month height
1 2004     5   9999
```

Obviously the real data is longer than this.

I want to merge the values from e into d

Try raw merge:

```
> merge(d,e)
[1] year   month  height
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Ok.  So add "by":

```
> merge(d,e,by=c("year","month"))
  year month height.x height.y
1 2004     5     2000     9999
```

Ok, it did an inner join, and got rid of all the original data in d.  So try left outer join:

```
> merge(d,e,by=c("year","month"),all.x = T)
  year month height.x height.y
1 2004     1     1000       NA
2 2004     5     2000     9999
3 2006     3     3000       NA
```

It did a join, and it's correct as per outer-join definition, but it didn't do what I want, which is to update the values in d from the values in e.  What I really want is more like an sql update:

```
for (year,month,height) in e:
    update d set d.height=e.height where d.year = e.year and d.month = e.month
```

ie the results I want would be:

```
> magic(d,e)
  year month height
1 2004     1   1000
2 2004     5   9999
3 2006     3   3000
```

Of course, I could just write a bunch of `for` loops, but I'm hoping there is some vectorized way of doing this?

Edit: my example had only one key column, but my real problem has two.  Updated the example to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the following approach is more straightforward:

```
rownames( d ) <- d$id
d[ e$id, ]$height <- e$height
```

Update: since your key is actually "year-month", you probably will be best off with the data table, but if you are not willing using that, here is what you can do:

```
rownames( d ) <- paste( d$year, d$month )
d[ paste( e$year, e$month ), ]$height <- e$height
```

Comment: I have two keys unfortunately, although my original question implicitly stated there are one, by giving example data with only one.  I've updated the question with an example with two keys.

Comment: In that case I recommend using `data.table` as suggested by @mnel. Although you could use `paste( year, month )` as your key (well, actually you have only one key: "year-month").

Comment: I went with this approach in the end, because whilst it seems to me a bit "hacky", it has zero learning curve.

Comment: It is "old style" for sure. Whenever I have to use `data.table`, I have to look up the idioms, while rownames and data.frames are already in my blood.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `data.table`

#### edit noting both e and d have a key defined by month and year

```
library(data.table)
DD <- as.data.table(d)
DE <- as.data.table(e)

setkey(DD,  year, month)
setkey(DE,  year, month)

DD[DE, height := i.height]
```

note that I have prefixed height with `i.` to ensure that it is reading the height value from the `i` component.

If you read the introduction to data.table vignette, you will quickly understand the relationship between rownames and data.table keys!